# How to track execution of Java Play after issuing Activator Run command?

Tags: java, class, playframework, terminal

I inherited big legacy code with Java Play. I can start what it needs to do from terminal from a specific folder by issuing command `activator run` .

Now I want to get more details on what is the first method/class being called, then second etc. (there is no much documentation in my project).

What is the best way to get started and track execution?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do this. Below are 2 techniques which I use generally

1) Enable play logger in debug mode. Play framework supports logback by default. You can enable the framework's logger using this configuration in logback.xml
`<logger name="play" level="INFO" />` More details on the default logger settings can be found here. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/SettingsLogger

2) application.conf gives a fair idea of the different parts of the application. One of the easiest ways to debug the flow is to start the application using the debug command and use the remote debugger to follow the flow
`activator -jvm-debug <remote debugger port> run`

If you have a class(usually named Module.java) in your root package, extending AbstractModule, that is a good starting point, since the eager dependency injections are usually defined here. It can give you an idea of the different parts of your application.